# Why does my _.some always return false using lodash?

Tags: angularjs, lodash

I m a beginner trying to learn . This is my object

```
$scope.selectedPartners =[
  {"name" : "Abc", "selected" : true},
  {"name" : "Abc", "selected" : true}
]
```

and my lodash is as below

```
var result = _.some($scope.selectedPartners, ['selected', true]);
```

if I log result it gives me false I am not sure if I understood right but this is supposed to give true.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are close except that the match argument should be an *object* and not an *array*.

```
 var result = _.some($scope.selectedPartners, {'selected': true});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/18zfjb7z/

Comment: @Vignesh yes, I see what you mean.

Comment: @Vignesh I think the documentation is wrong.  Property match short hand is **3** arguments. `_.some($var, 'selected', true);`

Comment: This could be a bug. I tried to open an issue at github for this, but github is down for me right now.